# CF7 hiding `.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok` after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to hide Contact Form 7's `wpcf7-mail-sent-ok` element, after the form has been sent. However, I'm getting some unexpected results and I'm not sure as to why.

**This is the code as per my footer.php file in WP.**

```
// Contact Form 7 mail sent...
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {

  $('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow').hide(0);

}, false);
```

**This is an example of what should be happening.**

```js
$('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow').hide(0);
```

```css
.wpcf7-response-output {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.8333rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" style="display: block;" role="alert">Thank you for your message. It has been sent.</div>
```

> **The Problem** - It's actually executing the reverse, strangely enough. What I mean is, it's waiting 5 seconds, then fading in then the box just sits there indefinitely.

Note: I'm receiving no errors in the console.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your event is firing as expected? You can check that just by adding a console.log inside your ```document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) { ... }```

Comment: I've just checked the console, via `console.log('its working...');` inside the function it appears to be functioning as expected. :/

Comment: I'm wondering if the Jq is firing before the element has been rendered? I'll try adding a delay before firing the hide event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some digging, It turns out the Jquery was firing before allowing the element to render, this caused some unexpected results.

I was able to resolve the issue by using the following;

```
// Contact Form 7 mail sent...
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow').hide(0);
  }, 5000);

}, false);
```

> Thanks for the assist guys.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use JS, you can accomplish the same thing via CSS

```
.wpcf7 .wpcf7-form .wpcf7-mail-sent-ok { 
    display: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: I know I could do it this way, but I want the message to be visible for a period of time, then disappear gracefully.

Comment: In that case, why not show a general notification on `wpcf7mailsent` , but anyways your jquery code looks fine,

Comment: Could you elaborate, what do you mean by general notification?

Comment: Hide the message via CSS , and instead of trying to manipulate the Dom via jquery which is slow , just show a notification (alert , popup) and hide that notification via CSS transition or similar,

Comment: Interesting thought. I may go with this. Thanks for the help.